# pure javascript dropdown DIV animation

Tags: javascript, animation, drop-down-menu

I'm tired to search google for this so I decided to ask professionals here. Is it possible and How to create an effect of drop down DIV like here http://137pillarshouse.com/accommodation -  the BOOK NOW block with pure javascript without jQuery or any libraries.

THanks

Comment: Since jQuery is written in Javascript, you can choose to do what you might otherwise do with jQuery without using it, albeit it may take you considerably longer to program it. The How is simply that you would be programing in JavaScript without the convenience of libraries. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well they didn't obfuscate javascript code, you can learn from their code.

## 1. http://137pillarshouse.com/js/script.js

```
// show/hide booking form
        $('#bookingpanel #booknow').click(function(){
            $('#quickbookingform').slideToggle(750,'easeOutQuart');
            $('#bookingpanel').toggleClass('open');
            $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Book <em>Now</em>' ? 'Close' : 'Book <em>Now</em>');
            return false;
        });
// Quick Booking Form
    $('#StartDateString').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',firstDay:1,minDate:1,maxDate:'+18m'});
```

## 2.

```
    <div id="bookingpanel" class="">
 <form action="https://www.luxuryroomreservations.com/en-GB/IBE/115/Landing/Index" method="post" id="quickbookingform" class="booking" style="display: none; ">
    <fieldset>
    <label for="StartDateString">Arrival Date</label>
    <input class="text hasDatepicker" id="StartDateString" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.StartDateString" type="text" value="">
     <label for="NoOfNights">Nights</label>
     <select id="CurrentBooking_CurrentUserSearch_NoOfNights" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.NoOfNights">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
        .....
    </select>
    <div class="left">
    <label for="NoOfAdults">Adults</label>
    <select id="NoOfAdults" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.NoOfAdults">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </div><!-- /.left -->
    <div class="right">
    <label for="NoOfChildren">Children</label>
    <select id="NoOfChildren" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.NoOfChildren">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div><!-- /.right -->
    <input id="CurrentBooking_CurrentUserSearch_AccountId" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.AccountId" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="CurrentBooking_CurrentUserSearch_SpecialRateCode" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.SpecialRateCode" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="CurrentBooking_CurrentUserSearch_IataCode" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.IataCode" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="CurrentBooking_CurrentUserSearch_HotelCode" name="CurrentBooking.CurrentUserSearch.HotelCode" type="hidden" value="HUCNXPH">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Check Availability" id="booking_submit"></p>
</fieldset>
</form><a href="#bookingpanel" id="booknow">Book <em>Now</em></a>
</div>
```

## 3. and a bit of CSS

### Mobile

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
#bookingpanel {
top: -10px;
right: 60px;
}
```

### desktop

```
#bookingpanel {
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
right: 20px;
z-index: 100;
width: 15em;
-moz-transition-duration: .25s;
-webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
-o-transition-duration: .25s;
-ms-transition-duration: .25s;
transition-duration: .25s;
}
```

the rest is up to you... style it a bit and you'll get there I'm sure :)